# Find upper and lower limit in S-chart

Tags: python, statistics, control-charts

Have a dataset, with individual standard deviations in python. How to I find the upper and lower control limits for these (in S-chart)?

Comment: Please provide more details - perhaps a snippet of the dataset

Comment: its a simple 12*8 dataset containing weights